# how do i authenticate 3rd party user to access my web API asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, claims-based-identity

I want to authenticate **3rd party** users to use my web API using claim based **authentication**. So please give me suggestions regarding this.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: https://identityserver.io/

Comment: 3rd party users as in facebook, google?

Comment: No, the user can be of any of my asp.net developed websites. @ Ruard van Elburg

Answer (score 0):

Please check out identityserver3 which uses oauth2 and openid connect protocols. 
You can choose sql, adfs or any custom providers to setup clients, scope and users

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Microsoft Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) for claim based authentication or use [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis) for enterprise applications which is built on top Identity Server.